# creating a drop down which gives values based on previous selection using php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i am trying to create a drop down, which populates the next field based on what you selected previously. I currently have 3 tables. So if production is selected, then all the date and times for that production show up in the next drop down.

```
CREATE TABLE Production(
 Title varchar(100) not null,
 BasicTicketPrice numeric(5,2) not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (Title)
);

CREATE TABLE Performance(
 PerfDate date not null,
 PerfTime time not null,
 Title varchar(100) not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime),
 FOREIGN KEY (Title) REFERENCES Production(Title)
);

CREATE TABLE Booking(
 BookingId varchar(255) not null,
 PerfDate date not null,
 PerfTime time not null,
 Name varchar(255) not null,
 Email varchar(255) not null,
 RowNumber char(6) not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (BookingId),
 FOREIGN KEY (PerfDate,PerfTime) REFERENCES Performance(PerfDate,PerfTime),
 FOREIGN KEY (RowNumber) REFERENCES Seat(RowNumber)
);
```

Here is how I am currently generating the selections for the form

```
<p><label for="production">Production: </label><select name="production"></p>
                    <?php 
                        $str = "SELECT Title FROM Production";
                        $result = $con->query($str);
                    ?>
                    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_row()): ?>
                    <?php $i = $row[0]; ?>
                    <option><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php 
                $i++;
                endwhile;?>
                </select>

<p><label for="date">Date: 
                </label><select name="date"></p>
                    <?php 
                        $strDate = "SELECT DISTINCT PerfDate FROM Performance";

                        $result = $con->query($strDate);
                    ?>
                    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_row()): ?>
                    <?php $i = $row[0]; ?>
                    <option><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php 
                $i++;
                endwhile;?>
                </select>
```

Comment: Not sure this fits into Q+A format - way too broad of a question. There are many techniques for doing this. Try googling "multiple dropdown dynamic load php mysql..."  and you'll find stuff like this: http://www.coderslexicon.com/populating-multiple-drop-downs-dynamically/

Answer (score 0):

You could try retrieve the selected value from 1st combobox using jquery and send it as parameter to the query that will populate the 2nd combobox and so on